# Modernity and black magic can coexist?

Tags: karma, modern-world

**1. In Buddhism, does black magic, magic spell exist? If it is, what's our belief system should be when we are taught to treat all with loving kindness?**
Often Black magic is not only concerned with negative, evil, demons, or bad things. Black magic spells and amulets can also be used for good, protection and as many other uses as there are human needs and desires.
Thailand being the predominately a Buddhist country, but this tends to be mixed with older animistic beliefs and some of them also have a strong belief in powerful supernatural entities.
Thailand is indeed one of the top tourist spot but some people also avoid going due to the fear of all these.
I for one, love Thailand a lot and been there many times but often curious about all this and at times confused.
I have read somewhere, some of the the top Monks in Thailand are that spiritually powerful to perform all these.
**2. Supposingly all these exist, what's the odd of being the target apart from jealousy?Supposingly if you are very much enlightened and practice meditation vigorously, does this make you any less of being the target?**
As some of the victims can be severely disturbed emotionally and in some cases it might even lead to death.

Comment: Read the chapter "Psychic Powers" in Mastering the Core Teachings of the Buddha by Daniel Ingram (get it from http://integrateddaniel.info/book), I find that is a good informative resource (note: it is perhaps not 100% orthodox, I cannot judge that; but it is clearly written). Summary: high concentration plus intent causes magick to happen; buddhists cultivate safe magick which are 4 brahmaviharas (metta, karuna, mudita, upekkha) plus perhaps teaching "power".

Comment: Can you elaborate on high concentration plus intent causes magick to happen? Does this means that one can never be too engaging?

Comment: Read that book, I am not knowledgeable enough to give more than pointers. My own experience is zero, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

***In Buddhism, does black magic, magic spell exist?***

I believe so... the Buddha seems to recognize some pretty powerful black magic, e.g.:

> “What do you think, householder? Suppose some recluse or brahmin came here possessed of supernormal power and attained to mastery of mind, and he spoke thus: ‘I will reduce this town of Nāḷandā to ashes with one mental act of hate.’ What do you think, householder, would such a recluse or brahmin be able to do that?”
>
> “Venerable sir, such a recluse or brahmin possessed of supernormal power and attained to mastery of mind would be able to reduce ten, twenty, thirty, forty, or even fifty Nāḷandās to ashes with one mental act of hate, so what does a single trivial Nāḷandā count for?”
>
> -- MN 56 (Bodhi, trans)

***If it is, what's our belief system should be when we are taught to treat all with loving kindness?***

I don't believe this changes our imperative to treat all with loving kindness...

> "Monks, even if bandits were to savagely sever you, limb by limb, with a double-handled saw, even then, whoever of you harbors ill will at heart would not be upholding my Teaching. Monks, even in such a situation you should train yourselves thus: 'Neither shall our minds be affected by this, nor for this matter shall we give vent to evil words, but we shall remain full of concern and pity, with a mind of love, and we shall not give in to hatred. On the contrary, we shall live projecting thoughts of universal love to those very persons, making them as well as the whole world the object of our thoughts of universal love — thoughts that have grown great, exalted and measureless. We shall dwell radiating these thoughts which are void of hostility and ill will.' It is in this way, monks, that you should train yourselves.
>
> -- MN 21 (Buddharakkhita, trans)

***2. Supposingly all these exist, what's the odd of being the target apart from jealousy?***

I don't think this question is relevant to our site.

***Supposingly if you are very much enlightened and practice meditation vigorously, does this make you any less of being the target?***

Maybe... to some extent enlightenment protects one from harm, but mostly it protects one from reacting to harm and therefore causing further retribution. The stories of Angulimala and Mogallana both exemplify this idea.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR version:**

It's possible to protect oneself using the foundations of mindfulness (satipatthana), virtues (sila) and by not having bad intentions.

I think the general idea is that through these, one would generate good karma that takes one away from falling to black magic.

**Long version:**

There's a discussion on [protection through Satipatthana](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/bl034.html) by Ven. Nyanaponika where he quotes SN 19:

> This is the right way," said the Blessed One and spoke further as
>   follows:
>
> "It is just as the apprentice said: 'I shall protect myself' — in that
>   way the foundations of mindfulness (satipatthana) should be practiced.
>   'I shall protect others' — in that way the foundations of mindfulness
>   should be practiced. Protecting oneself, one protects others;
>   protecting others, one protects oneself.
>
> "And how does one, in protecting oneself, protect others? By the
>   repeated and frequent practice of meditation.
>
> "And how does one, in protecting others, protect oneself? By patience
>   and forbearance, by a non-violent and harmless life, by loving
>   kindness and compassion."

In the [Atta-rakkhita Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn03/sn03.005.than.html), there is discussion on self-protection through virtues (sila):

> Those who engage in bodily misconduct, verbal misconduct, & mental
>   misconduct leave themselves unprotected. Even though a squadron of
>   elephant troops might protect them, a squadron of cavalry troops, a
>   squadron of chariot troops, a squadron of infantry troops might
>   protect them, still they leave themselves unprotected. Why is that?
>   Because that's an external protection, not an internal one. Therefore
>   they leave themselves unprotected. But those who engage in good bodily
>   conduct, good verbal conduct, & good mental conduct have themselves
>   protected. Even though neither a squadron of elephant troops, a
>   squadron of cavalry troops, a squadron of chariot troops, nor a
>   squadron of infantry troops might protect them, still they have
>   themselves protected. Why is that? Because that's an internal
>   protection, not an external one. Therefore they have themselves
>   protected."

And finally protection through not having bad intentions in [Dhammapada 124](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=124):

> The bhikkhus then asked the Buddha, "Venerable Sir, is the wife of the
>   hunter who is a sotapanna, also not guilty of taking life, if she has
>   been getting things like nets, bows and arrows for her husband when he
>   goes out hunting?" To this question the Buddha answered, "Bhikkhus,
>   the sotapannas do not kill, they do not wish others to get killed. The
>   wife of the hunter was only obeying her husband in getting things for
>   him. Just as the hand that has no wound is not affected by poison, so
>   also, because she has no intention to do evil she is not doing any
>   evil."
>
> Then the Buddha spoke in verse as follows:
>
> If there is no
>   wound on the hand, one may handle poison; poison does not affect one
>   who has no wound; there can be no evil for one who has no evil
>   intention.

Comment: Wow...that's very deep, will try to digest.Thanks for sharing anyway! =)

Comment: Can this answer be edited to include a tl;dr version at the top or bottom?

Comment: Anthony - Pls go ahead and edit if you may, thanks!

Comment: I've edited it to say that.

Comment: Thanks ruben2020. Sunset_Limited, i wanted to but at the time i was sleepy and couldn't understand the full text.

Comment: I think the general idea is that through these, one would generate good karma that takes one away from falling to black magic.

Answer (score 0):

If your really afraid of black magic in Thailand remember,if you don't bear any ill will it "bounces" back to the owner.In other words if your a good person or virtuous someone's ill will can not harm you.Not even a powerful nature spirit can harm you if your heart is pure.A virtuous person is respected by other beings.Take refuge in your virtue.Your sila gives you the confidence to stand up and face hostility   because your blameless.Your whole.I advice that you recite the Paritta Protection Book.And do a lot of metta practice.If someone is going through great lengths to spread and concentrate I'll will on you.You should be doing the opposite.For hatred can only be overcome by love.

Comment: Bearing of no ill will towards that person u mean? What if you are the indirect target?