# Spiritual Potential and Consequences of Actions

Tags: anger, non-violence

Upon reading [this](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8163/7302) question, I wondered: would a person with great spiritual potential, without compassion, be more likely to cause great harm than an average person? Not intentionally, but say due to anger or hate; would this person be akin to a politician with great power who's actions can affect more?

**Thus, would spiritual potent individuals' actions have greater consequences under the effect of negative states?**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "spiritual potential", you probably meant those with supernormal powers/[Iddhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhi) capability right? because those with higher spiritual potential would naturally tend to act/speak/think in a more skillful way than those who don't. If that's the case then sure. Just like that common expression "with great power comes great responsibility". A foot soldier can save or kill someone with just his weapon, but an emperor can build or annihilate an entire country with just an order! So probably a more apt expression would be: "with great power comes great kammic consequences".

Comment: Yet think what a mind-master is able to, not even use words. Kamma by mind is far more powerful than physical actions could.